# Draw Image with scaling on canvas

Tags: flutter

How to draw image with scaling at particular offset on canvas? I want to draw Image & text at the bottom right corner, I have Offsets & image both, how to scale image only & set with text at specific offsets?

Comment: `Canvas.drawImageRect` (or `paintImage` top level function)

Comment: but how to scale image?

Comment: everything is in the official documentation for those two functions - see https://api.flutter.dev/index.html and search them in the top right "Search API docs"  field

Comment: I have tried with canvas.scale() but after scaling it, while using canvas.drawImage() it changes offsets because of scale. How to solve it?

Comment: so what problems do you have with `drawImageRect` method? what does not work?

Comment: I have tried drawImageRect also, but not getting proper results after scale. can you please share some working example?

Comment: `var size = Size(image.width, image.height); var src = Offset.zero & size; dst = drawOffset & size / 3; canvas.drawImageRect(image, src, dst, Paint());` - it draws your image scaled down by 1/3 with top-left corner at `drawOffset`

Comment: and if you have problems with aligning the rect at bottom right corner use `Alignment.inscribe` method

Comment: sure, your welcome

Comment: btw [paintImage](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/paintImage.html) has both easier yet more rich interface - the whole image is drawn so no need for using `src` rect, but you can use `alignment`, `colorFilter` etc

Comment: Okay thanks, i will check paintImage also.

Comment: `paintImage(
canvas: canvas,
image: image,
scale: 3.0,
alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
fit: BoxFit.none,
rect: Offset.zero & canvasSize,
);`